# Matching several keywords against articles containing them then order by desc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to figure out how to solve this problem, but can't wrap my head around it- or to find the best way to do it. What I want to achieve is the following (Kw stands for keyword).

**Existing kw in db across all articles:**
Kw1, Kw2, Kw3, Kw4, Kw5

**Articles using the keywords**

Art1: Kw1, Kw2, Kw3

Art2: Kw1, Kw2, Kw4

Art3: Kw4, Kw1, Kw5

Art4: Kw5, Kw4, Kw2

**Keywords to match (submitted by user)**

Kw1, Kw2, Kw3

**Rank based on most number of keyword matches**

Art 1

Art 2

Art 3 and 4

**Tech specs**

I am trying to achieve this using a ASP.NET MVC project with Entity Framework. The project is connected to a MS SQL database containing one table with the articles, and another table with the keywords connected with each article.

My initial thoughts was to use LINQ in some way, but I find it hard to figure out just how to do this, if even possible.

All help sending me towards the right path on how to solve this would be very much appreciated!

**Edit: Data structure**

```
**KeywordTbl**
[KnowledgeDatabaseKeywordId] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Keyword]                    NVARCHAR (64) NOT NULL,
[KnowledgeDatabaseId]        INT           NOT NULL,

**ArticlesTbl**
[KnowledgeDatabaseId] INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Title]               NVARCHAR (200)  NOT NULL,
[Summary]             NVARCHAR (1000) NOT NULL,
[Article]             NVARCHAR (MAX)  NOT NULL,
```

**Example**

```
**ArticlesTbl**
KnowledgeDatabaseId = 1
Title = "My title"
Summary = "A short summary"
Article = "Longer text"

**KeywordTbl**
KnowledgeDatabaseKeywordId = 1
Keyword = "Kw1"
KnowledgeDatabaseId = 1

KnowledgeDatabaseKeywordId = 2
Keyword = "Kw2"
KnowledgeDatabaseId = 1
```

Comment: You should look into a full text index.

Comment: May not be the best solution, but using linq you can run parallel query per keyword and then merge the results and sort it.

Comment: I take it that when you say the articles contain the keywords, these are keywords that make up the text body of the article or are they separately stored keywords that are used to categorise the article?

Comment: iamdave - the keywords are separatley stored, they can be seen as e.g. blog tags/to categorize the article.

Comment: What is the data structure that holds these keywords?  This is very important in getting help that is actually relevant to your situation.  Please add you data structure and some test data.  Also, if you want to reference a username so we are notified that you have tagged us, use the `@` symbol before the name, like this: `@Subtractive`

Comment: Thank you @iamdave - I have edited my post and added the data structure!

Comment: You should be able to apply what I have done in my answer below to your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing what your data structure is this is a rather hard question to answer, but hopefully the below is a good starting point to get your head around how SQL may be able to handle what you want.

If you have your `Keywords` held in a table alongside your `Articles`, you can create a table of `Keywords` to look up, either with temp tables, table variables or derived tables (I have used table variables for ease of writing the example) and then count all the matches that are returned from a `left join`:

```
declare @t table (ArticleID int, Keyword nvarchar(10));
insert into @t values (1,'Kw1'),(1,'Kw2'),(1,'Kw3'),(2,'Kw1'),(2,'Kw2'),(2,'Kw4'),(3,'Kw4'),(3,'Kw1'),(3,'Kw5'),(4,'Kw5'),(4,'Kw4'),(4,'Kw2');

declare @kw table (Keyword nvarchar(10));
insert into @kw values('Kw1'),('Kw2'),('Kw3');

select t.ArticleID
        ,count(k.Keyword) as Matches
from @t t
    left join @kw k
        on(t.Keyword = k.Keyword)
group by t.ArticleID
order by Matches desc
        ,t.ArticleID;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+---------+
| ArticleID | Matches |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 |       3 |
|         2 |       2 |
|         3 |       1 |
|         4 |       1 |
+-----------+---------+
```